# call a function only once in each iteration of an *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have this code, with which a `*ngFor` calls a function (`randomData(i)`) many times in the same iteration.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
     <div
        [ngClass]="{
        'd-none':
            (randomColor(i).clase == 'categoria1' && !categoria1) ||
            (randomColor(i).clase == 'categoria2' && !categoria2) ||
            (randomColor(i).clase == 'categoria3' && !categoria3)
        }">
        <div id="ribbon-container">
        <span id="ribbon" [ngClass]="randomColor(i).clase">
          {{randomColor(i).categoria}}
        </span>
        </div>
        <div>
        <img [src]="'./assets/img/emotions/' + randomColor(i).imagen" class="img-fluid imagen_tarjeta_emociones float-right"
        />
    </div>
 </ng-container>
```

---

```
randomData(i) {
    if (i == 0) {
    return {
        categoria: "Categoría 1",
        clase: "categoria1",
        imagen: "Alegria.png",
    };
    } else if (i % 2) {
    return {
        categoria: "Categoría 2",
        clase: "categoria2",
        imagen: "Enfado.png",
    };
    } else if (i % 3) {
    return {
        categoria: "Categoría 3",
        clase: "categoria3",
        imagen: "Neutro.png",
    };
  }
}
```

Is there a way that this function is only called once for each iteration? maybe store the value of `randomData(i)` in a temporary variable in the template or something to avoid running the function so many times.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't run any functions in your template. It has a very large performance impact. It looks like every item already has a 'category' property. Why not take out the function, and just write `[ngClass]="item.categoria", and then make a separate css rule for every category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

process your `data` in your ts file like this:

```
data.forEach((item, i) => {
      item = Object.assign(item, this.randomData(i));
});
```

Then update your template:replace all the `randomData(i)` with `item`

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
     <div
        [ngClass]="{
        'd-none':
            item.clase == 'categoria1' && !categoria1) ||
            item.clase == 'categoria2' && !categoria2) ||
            item.clase == 'categoria3' && !categoria3)
        }">
        <div id="ribbon-container">
        <span id="ribbon" [ngClass]="item.clase">
          {{item.categoria}}
        </span>
        </div>
        <div>
        <img [src]="'./assets/img/emotions/' + item.imagen" class="img-fluid imagen_tarjeta_emociones float-right"
        />
    </div>
 </ng-container>
```